# ParallelMap not using all of the available kernels

Tags: parallelization

Please note: I cannot provide the code here, since the project is far too big to post at any Internet forum.

I have a computer with eight logical cores.

[image: Task Manager]

I have Mathematica Version 10.0.2, and I am making a call to `ParallelMap[]` with `Method -> Automatic`.  (In serial, the computation takes about 90 minutes, so in parallel, I would expect the computation to take about 30 minutes or so.)  For the first few seconds of the call, the kernel status monitor shows the message `4 kernels running, busy`, with the word "busy" being displayed in red.  Then, after those few seconds, the message changes to the one shown below:

[image]

Now the kernels are apparently idle.  And sure enough, I see absolutely no speed-up.  I have repeated the process with `Method -> "FinestGrained"` and `Method -> CoarsestGrained`, but the result has been exactly the same as with `Automatic`.

I would like to mention that my input does not have any global variable updates.  I am not expecting any contention or race conditions.

Is there anything I can do to understand why I am not seeing a speed-up?

Comment: Have you tried the same things with another (smaller) parallelizable load?

Comment: Yes, I did.  For trivial functions--such as `ParallelMap[# + 1&, Range[100]]`, everything happens so fast that I don't get to see any sustained behaviour.  When I restrict the input size of my problem to about 50% the size (by taking the first 250 elements) I see a similar behaviour as that described in the question.  I have not tried the call for smaller inputs.  Maybe I should try it.

Comment: What does `ParallelMap[Pause[1] &, Range[5]] // AbsoluteTiming` return?

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries My Mathematica is currently running the computation even as I write.  As soon as that computation is over, I will run your snippet and post the answer.  Thanks.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries I ran `AbsoluteTiming[ParallelMap[Pause[2] &, Range[5]]]` and got the output `{4.000240, {Null, Null, Null, Null, Null}}`.  So I'm definitely seeing some speed-up here.

Comment: Well, without seeing your program and with the other info you provided I'm a bit out of options. You don't write to disk or use swap space because of memory constraints, do you? Is it possible to reduce your program to something that is postable but still shows the same problem?

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries I am trying my best to capture the essence of the programme in a mini example.  Basically, I start with a list of associations, and add key-value pairs to each association in the list.  After that, I call `Dataset` on the list.  I will try to replicate the behaviour in an example and update the question.  Thank you very much.